# How to continuously generate 2D-Lists until a certain specification is met

Tags: python

I've written the following Python Program:

This program generates a 30x30 2D List and places 10 marks randomly around the grid. I want to modify this program to continuously generate this 30x30 2D whilst placing marks and to stop only when each mark is a set amount of spaces apart (ex minimum 5 meters apart). I know I'd have to use the Pythagorean theorem to do this but not sure how to implement it into my code.

```py
import random
listSize = 30
marks = 10
grid = []
for i in range(listSize): 
    grid.append([0] * listSize)
for i in range(marks):
    x = random.randint(0, listSize - 1)
    y = random.randint(0, listSize - 1)
    grid[x][y] = 1 
for row in grid:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.What do u mean by `stop only when each mark is a set amount of spaces apart`.Set amount of spaces apart from the previous mark?

Comment: No 2 marks can be closer than 5 meters to each other for all 10 marks.

Comment: Instead of continuously creating new grids, why not just place the marks according to the restraints?

Comment: Because the marks being placed are randomly generated (look at my code)

Comment: So in this case the distance between your marks should be greater than 5.Am i right?

Comment: Since you are randomly generating the co-ordinates its is very hard to keep track of your `marks`.It would be better if you use a specific algorithm to generate the marks rather than randomly generating them

Comment: @SreeramM yeah ur right

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing marks in the grid, you should create an addition list which stores the x,y positions of each mark, then loop over that to check if each pair satisfies the condition.  So something like this:

```
import math

points = [(0,0), (5,10), (100,200)]
for n, point_n in enumerate(points):
    for point_m in points[n+1:]:
        if math.dist(point_n, point_m) < 5:
            print('distance less than 5!')
```

Note `math.dist` is only available in Python3.8 and higher, you will have to code the distance function yourself in lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat naive hit-or-miss approach:

```
from math import sqrt
from random import randint
from itertools import combinations

def dist(p,q):
    return sqrt((p[0]-q[0])**2 + (p[1]-q[1])**2)

def rand_points(n,k):
    """picks n random points with coordinates in range(k)"""
    #assumes that this is feasible!
    choices = set()
    for _ in range(n):
        while True:
            p = (randint(0,k-1),randint(0,k-1))
            if p not in choices:
                choices.add(p)
                break
    return list(choices)

def check_points(points,min_dist):
    """checks if each point is at least min_dist away from other points"""
    return all(dist(p,q) >= min_dist for p,q in combinations(points,2))

def find_points(grid_size,num_points,min_dist,max_trials = 1000):
    for trial in range(max_trials):
        points = rand_points(num_points,grid_size)
        if check_points(points,min_dist):
            return points
```

For example:

```
>>> find_points(30,10,5)
[(26, 9), (6, 0), (29, 23), (17, 13), (12, 19), (2, 22), (2, 28), (3, 9), (1, 16), (18, 5)]
```

It is of course easy to load such of list of points into a grid:

```
def grid_from_points(grid_size,points):
    grid = [[0]*grid_size for _ in range(grid_size)]
    for p,q in points:
        grid[p][q] = 1
    return grid
        points = rand_points(num_points,grid_size)
        if check_points(points,min_dist):
            return points
```